# docker compose on docker desktop not reading --env-file

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, sbt-docker-compose

Im running docker desktop on windows.

my .env file looks like this:

```
VERSION=local
ENV=local
```

my .env_dev file looks like this:

```
VERSION=dev
ENV=dev
```

my dev docker-compose has this snippet:

```
services:
  my_app:
    container_name: my_app_${ENV}
    image: "my_app:${VERSION}"
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      target: my_app_${ENV}
      args:
        ENV: ${ENV:-local}
    environment:
      ENV:${ENV:-local}
      PYTHONPATH:${PYTHONPATH}
```

my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:latest as base
ARG ENV
....
....
FROM base as my_app_dev
COPY "./.devcontainer/.env_$ENV"
```

When i do a:

````
docker system prune -f
docker compose --env-file .env_dev  build --no-cache```
````

I get this error:

```
 => ERROR [my_app my_app_dev 1/3] COPY ./.devcontainer/.env_local
```

It seems to still be reading the .env file. Why is it not reading the ENV value from the .env_dev file, which should have the value 'dev' and so the line it should be `COPY ./.devcontainer/.env_dev`

Comment: Shouldn't `context` be `../.devcontainer`? I don't think you need to specify `dockerfile` then either, since you are using the default name. I don't know where your `.env_local` file is, but if it is in the `.devcontainer` dir it will probably work. Looks like docker is looking for the file in folder where the compose file is and not finding `.devcontainer` there.

Comment: env_local is nowhere, it doesn't exist.  If I'm using the --env-file arg as indicated, it should use the .env_prod file and pass 'prod' to to the docker file when building. Instead it's still using .env file and passing 'local'.  The context isn't the issue I thon as its finding the .env file fine and I can build fine for a local env.